# Google Chrome clears CSS styles for current page when opening link in new tab or opening a new window

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is odd one, I was troubleshooting for 3 days.

Only happening in `Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)` on Windows.

Web server must have header set (meta tag doesn't work in this case):

Apache's .htaccess: `Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"`
or nginx: `add_header Cache-Control no-cache;`

You can't recreate it using jsfiddle or built-in code snippet, because css file must be loaded separately using `<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`. (but I will include code in snippet anyways).

Steps to recreate:

1. Visit: http://test.xmpsoft.net/
2. Click on link 1 (should reload the page);
3. Click on link 2 (should bring up new tab with the same page);
4. Switch to the original tab and repeat same steps;
5. All CSS styles are gone from the original tab.
6. If not, repeat same steps again.

Please assist to make sure where is nothing wrong with the code before I submit it to Google.

Thanks.

P.S. There is another way or recreating it (that's why I mentioned 'new window' in my Title: Visit same page, reload it, right click -> Inspect (new Development Tools window opens), switch back to the page (repeat if not able to recreate).

```css
.menu div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 15em;
 height: 15em;
}

.red {
 background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<title>Chrome bug</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='red'>Red</div>
  <div class='yellow'>Yellow</div>
  <div class='green'>Green</div>
</div>
<a href='/'>1. Reload this page</a><br>
<a href='/' target='_blank'>2. Open same page in new tab</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is definitely a strange issue. Good luck figuring it out!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Could you please look at the network tab in chrome dev tools and see if CSS is loaded? You might want to enable the "preserve log" option.

Comment: Bug is reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648237&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort= Same issue here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/dbPsJol-dkc/jGbryUazAgAJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was fixed by Google developers and <strike>will be merged to the stable channel soon</strike> already merged into Version 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit).

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648237#c6

Comment: I was going crazy trying to find where the problem was in my code! Great news!